# Using a class as a value type within another class in the header file

Tags: c++, class, object, header

I have run into another problem with writing my cafeteria simulation project. The idea is that I'm writing three classes(**student, group, and tray**) and a  main program to simulate a running cafeteria. The **tray** holds certain information, such as color and the name of the **student** who picks it up, as well as the total amount that the food on the tray adds up to. After each **tray** is paired with a **student**, it is pushed onto a **group** stack. This is where the problem comes up. I get all sorts of errors when attempting to define **group** functions with **tray** arguments. Below is the code of the two classes as well as some errors, again, I would appreciate any insight:

```
    class group
{
public:
    //CONSTRUCTOR
    group(string color="nocolor"){group_color=color; group_total=0;}
    //MEMBER FUNCTIONS for group class:
    void set_color(string new_color){group_color=new_color;}
    void add_member(simic_217A::tray new_member){assert(group_color==new_member.color());members.push(new_member);group_total+=new_member.price();}
    //void add_it_up();
    void remove_one() {members.pop();}
    void empty_group(){assert(!members.empty()); while(!members.empty()){members.pop();}} //    NEWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWw

    //CONST MEMBER FUNCTIONS for group class:
    string color() const {return group_color;}
    double  price_tot() const {assert(!members.empty()); return group_total;}
    bool is_empty() const {return members.empty();}
    simic_217A::tray top_item() const {return members.top();}

private:
    double group_total;
    string group_color;
    stack<simic_217A::tray> members;
};

//NONMEMBER FUNCTION for group class:
    std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& outs, const group& info);


class tray
{
public:
    //CONSTRUCTOR
    tray(string color="nocolor"){tray_color=color; tray_student_name="noname"; tray_price=0;}
    //MEMBER FUNCTIONS for tray class:
    void pick_up(student nextinline){tray_student_name= nextinline.get_name(); tray_price= nextinline.price(); nextinline.set_group(tray_color) ;}
    string set_color(string color){tray_color=color;}
    void drop_tray(){tray_student_name="noname"; tray_price=0;} 
    //CONST MEMBER FUNCTION for tray class:
    string tray_name() const {return tray_student_name;}
    double tray_price_func() const {return tray_price;}
    string color () const {return tray_color;}
private:
    string tray_color;
    string tray_student_name;
    double   tray_price;
};
  }
```

Here are a couple of errors that I get when trying to compile:

```
    error C2039: 'tray' : is not a member of 'simic_217A'

    error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'tray'

    error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'top_item'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition for tray needs to occur **before** any classes that depend on it, such as group. Otherwise the compiler won't know what a tray is.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know the compiler wouldn't recognize it. So in the case that I had each class including each of the two other types (ex./ group has tray and student types, tray has group and student types, etc.) I would have to switch something out in order to be able to compile, right? (This is probably an unrealistic situation but I'm wondering if there are any ways around this in general)

Comment: @Mike what you've got is a circular dependency. They should be avoided by changing your class design, there are plenty of tricks for doing so, such as the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)